# Python: how to let string format use dictionary lookup?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, format, lookup

I was trying on python 2.7 and:

```
b={'name':'abc',address:'xyz'}
print 'hello %(name)' % b
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-92-bc9585e20f74> in <module>()
----> 1 'hello %(name)' % b
```

I wish this statement will display `hello abc`, how to correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shall try like this

```
b={'name':'abc','address':'xyz'}
print 'hello %s' % b['name']
```

Comment: There is no need to convert the variable `address` to a string, that completely changes the code. It is obvious the OP uses `address` as he otherwise would get a different error.

Comment: Oh.. okay.. Got it. Thanks for the review

Answer (score 4):

You are missing an 's' after the closing `)`:

```
print 'hello %(name)s' % b
```

As it seems you are new to python, you should prepare for the future and start using `from __future__ import print_function` as well look into using the `.format()` that @Lolgast already indicated:

```
from __future__ import print_function

b = {'name':'abc', address:'xyz'}
print('hello {name}'.format(**b))
```

Comment: Why the ```from __future__ import print_function```? While I have used it for some specific purposes, the normal 2.7 behavior works just fine in general. I would say preparing for the future (if necessary) would be done by just switching to python 3 all together.

Comment: @Lolgast Like I indicated, you should IMO prepare for the future. Python 2.7 is the last version to support `print` as a statement. At some point you'll need to be compatible with/use/switch to 3.x and then `print()` is mandatory and you're stuck with a habit of leaving out the `()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `string.format` function:

```
b={'name':'abc',address:'xyz'}
print 'hello {name}'.format(**b)     #Note that you need to explode the dict
```